# HTTP over SOCKS with Emacs' url package

Tags: url, emacs, proxy, socks

How to get EMACS to use a SOCKS proxy?

There is a lot of information on using an HTTP proxy, but not much on a SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://www.andreer.com/ and it seems to be the only place that has this information.  Without permission, I am copying the information here so if the site goes down it will not be lost.  Thanks to Andreer, whoever you are:

> While I'm not using this site for anything else, here's something
>   useful it can say: To use emacs' url/http library over a SOCKS proxy,
>   configure the proxy with M-x customize-group socks, and (setq
>   url-gateway-method 'socks). I couldn't find that documented anywhere
>   on the web, and it took me an hour and a half to figure it out, so
>   there you go.